# Effect on Q factor and resonant frequency when scaling down a damped oscillator to micro / nano scales

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, vibrations, scaling

I've always just accepted that as you scale down a mechanical system the frequency and Q factor both increase. But how exactly do they scale? Linearly? With the square of reduction in size? Or maybe some more complicated relationship.

If the properties of the materials are constant, how would $Q$ and $\omega_0$ scale as the length scales?

**My attempt so far**

Since density is constant, mass (and also the force due to gravity) scales down with $s^3$. Where $s$ is the scaling factor.

$$M\propto s^3$$

I think the stiffness of the material will be constant as length scales down, as well as the viscous damping coefficient of the material.(Is this correct?).

Therefore the damping ratio scales:

$$\zeta \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{s^3}}$$

The undamped frequency will scale:

$$\omega_0 \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{s^3}}$$

Therefore the natural frequency the system will oscillate at scales:

$$\omega_1 \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{s^3}}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{s^3}}$$

And the Q factor scales:

$$Q \propto \sqrt{s^3}$$

But these equations do not agree with what I have been taught. I've been taught that generally as you scale down, things speed up. What am I doing wrong, and what is the real relationship between size, natural frequency, and Q factor? Also, just because the natural frequency and Q factor scale a certain way, does this mean the operating frequency of the system will scale the same? E,g, if a [mems resonator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_system_oscillator) is driven with an electrostatic force (by means of an AC voltage source), is it likely that the resonator will be designed to operate at its resonant frequency?

Comment: what is a Q-factor?

Comment: It is a parameter that describes how wide the peak is on a frequency vs energy graph. The peak on the graph is the resonant frequency, for a high Q factor this is a sharp peak  (i.e the amplitude will be small when driven at frequencies either side of the resonant frequency). Physicly it is a ratio of the energy stored in the ocilator to the energy lost per cycle.

Comment: link/defining equation? it seems that you wanna have your equations checked. give your calculations then.

Also: your equation for $\omega_1$ is not well behaved for $s\le1$. take $s=1$ (no scale) then $\omega_1 \propto 0$ ??

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator All equations were taken from this. The derivations for how the parameters scale were done by just looking at the equations in this wiki, determining what is constant, and how each parameter scales with size

Comment: I guess the problem comes with, not scaling parameters like $k$ and $c$

Comment: Maybe, but this makes the problem quite complicated. I imagine the solution should be quite simple. Another way to ask my question would be: Everyone knows that smaller bells ring at higher frequencies when struck, but how exactly does this frequency scale with size of the bell? I imagine the maths behind this shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: This comes with waves canceling each other while reflected at the "ends" of the resonator. Greater objects allow for greater wavelengths of sound to form standing waves, which are not damped so quickly. Therefore lower frequencies will be present more longer resulting in a much deeper tone for large objects. You should look at coupled harmonic oszillators or [vibrating strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrating_string) for that matter. I'm not sure if a single oscillator could explain that behaviour